# How to search for a message by a specific ts

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to get the parent message of a threaded reply with the Slack API. When a new reply is put, it has a "thread_ts" attached to it, which corrsponds to its parent message's "ts". I tried to do a searchall with the ts as the query but this didn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

See Slack's docs on [retrieving a single message](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history#retrieving_a_single_message) with `channels.history`. This "selecting 1 item from a range" approach should also work with other channel history methods and `conversations.history`.

The easiest way is to provide the `thread_ts` value you want to look up as the `latest` parameter to `conversations.history`, along with the containing channel ID as `channel`, and a `limit` of `1` to ask for a single message. You will need the corresponding `*:history` scope to make the request.

Example:

`GET /api/conversations.history?token=TOKEN_WITH_CHANNELS_HISTORY_SCOPE&channel=C2EB2QT8A&latest=1476909142.000007&inclusive=true&limit=1`

Comment: Just wanted to stress the importance of setting `inclusive` to `true`, because by default the message is not included. I usually set both `oldest` and `latest` parameters, so I won't have to worry about sorting and get only the message with specified ts.

Comment: The link seems to be outdated and the relevant documentation seems to be moved to here: https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving